# Deleting an Object in the Blender Game Engine using a Mouse Click Event

Tags: python, game-engine

This might be a simple question, but how would one delete an object on a mouse click when the object is clicked? Picture below.

Logic bricks or python is accepted. Thanks in advance 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add these logic bricks to the object you want to be deleted it the game!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ei4h.png